# Are there any simply connected parallelizable 4-manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, 4-manifolds

On pp. 166 of Scorpan's "The Wild World of 4--manifolds", he gives an example of a parallelizable 4-manifold ($S^1\times S^3$) and then asserts: "there are no simply connected examples". It's confusing to me whether he means that there are no such examples in general, or examples that are 4-manifolds. In any case, here is my question:

> Do there exist (compact, smooth, oriented) simply connected manifolds that are parallelizable? 4-manifolds?

(Recall that a manifold is called parallelizable if it has a trivial tangent bundle.)

Comment: At the very least "compact" should be added, otherwise just take $\mathbb{R}^n$. In fact, any contractible manifold will be both simply connected and parallelizable.

Comment: @Matt you're absolutely right. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simply connected smooth compact 4-manifold has its homology concentrated in even degrees, by Poincare duality.  Thus its Euler characteristic is positive.  By the Poincare-Hopf index theorem, such a manifold can have no nowhere vanishing vector field, and so is certainly not parallelizable.

Answer (score 5):

At least $S^3$ is a lie group so parallelizable.

Comment: More generally, the orthogonal groups have simply connected compact universal covering spaces.

Comment: The question is specifically about 4-manifolds. We could say now that, as a corollary, that there are no 4-dimensional simply connected Lie groups.